# Concatenate two columns and replace one of them with a result in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, subquery, concatenation

I have a table where in column `location` there is the folder of the file, e.g. `'/home/ubuntu/test'` and in the `name` column, there is the filename  e.g. `'test1.png'`.

I would like to replace the `location` column with the full path, e.g. `'/home/ubuntu/test/test.png'`.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE experiment_11.microscope_image_files
SET location=(SELECT concat_ws('/', location::text, name::text) 
FROM experiment_11.microscope_image_files);
```

but I get the following error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: Try `UPDATE experiment_11.microscope_image_files SET location= concat_ws('/', location::text, name::text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a subquery. Instead, use just:

```
UPDATE experiment_11.microscope_image_files SET
location = location || '/' || name
```

---

The error was caused by the subquery returning more than 1 row ( actually it was returning *all* the rows), but when used as an expression (as you did) it must return either 0 or 1 rows.